# Необходимо обрезать угол изображения с помощью блока

Tags: javascript, html, css, вёрстка

На фрагменте видна картинка, которая находится в блоке, у которого в свою очередь есть фон, с обрезанным углом.
Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы у той самой картинки был обрезан угол, но я не могу понять, как это можно сделать. Буду очень признателен любой помощи, возможно есть вариант сделать это через js(только не jquery, пожалуйста!!!).

```css
.forAngle {
  background: linear-gradient(-135deg, white 10px, red 0);
}

.filesView_col3 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 40px;
  max-width: 150px;
  height: max-content;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 30px;
}

.filesView_col3_img{
        width: 100%;
}

.right-click-area{
    cursor: pointer;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100px;
    max-height: max-content;
    position: relative;
}

#myImg{
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
}
#myImg:hover{
    opacity: 0.7;
}
```

```html
<div class="filesView_col3">
  <div class="forAngle">
    <img class="filesView_col3_img checkSlider right-click-area" src="https://sun9-17.userapi.com/impg/w0hPmi8E7sGOq1CHJqZOsRXcDt0TLcbCBISEpg/BS1D0HUKse4.jpg?size=750x750&quality=96&proxy=1&sign=53403fd414deb33ca28531c56d86f162&type=album" id="myImg">
  </div>
  File
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно использовать `css-маску` (синтаксис похож на `background`)

```css
.forAngle {
  background: linear-gradient(-135deg, white 10px, red 0);
}

.filesView_col3 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 40px;
  max-width: 150px;
  height: max-content;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 30px;
}

.filesView_col3_img{
        width: 100%;
}

.right-click-area{
    cursor: pointer;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100px;
    max-height: max-content;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-mask: linear-gradient(-135deg, transparent 10px, black 0);
}

#myImg{
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
}
#myImg:hover{
    opacity: 0.7;
}
```

```html
<div class="filesView_col3">
  <div class="forAngle">
    <img class="filesView_col3_img checkSlider right-click-area" src="https://sun9-17.userapi.com/impg/w0hPmi8E7sGOq1CHJqZOsRXcDt0TLcbCBISEpg/BS1D0HUKse4.jpg?size=750x750&quality=96&proxy=1&sign=53403fd414deb33ca28531c56d86f162&type=album" id="myImg">
  </div>
  File
</div>
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо!!!

Comment: А есть ли какой-то ещё вариант не под webkit браузеры?

Comment: Он работает и в фоксе и в сафари. IE, понятное дело, пролетает.

Comment: @zhurof можно ведь для кросс браузерного решения использовать [clippPath](https://caniuse.com/?search=clippath%20svg), [mask SVG](https://caniuse.com/?search=mask%20svg), работает везде и в IE

Comment: @Alexandr_TT , можно конечно использовать и `svg` - решения, но про `IE` в этом вопросе ни слова не сказано. Да и решение на `css` получается в одну строчку, а на `svg` это приличное количество разметки, как ни крути ))   Опять же в наших силах и интересах делать так, чтобы этот "браузер" побыстрее издох, а его пользователи страдали от всяческих визуальных лишений

Comment: @zhurof насчет этого браузера (IE) согласен, обоими руками за :) Edge перешел на webkit, так что тут всё OK , а вот насчет CSS не согласен, на svg решения, как правило короче Посмотри сколько строчек стилей, Вам пришлось написать. вернее скопировать из вопроса

Comment: @Alexandr_TT , то всё авторские стили. Непосредственно решение вопроса (обрезка картинки) заняло всего одну строчку `css`. + я не уверен, что с `svg`-решением можно будет сделать `auto` высоту для картинки.